# javascript inherit is dangerous

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

How can we prevent the dangerous behavior in the code below?

```
var ee = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require("util");

util.inherits(strr, ee);

function strr() {
  ee.call(this);
  this._events = 0;  // modify the private member value in parent
}
```

If you are not aware this._events is a **private variable member** in the parent EventEmitter object, then the inner data is undermined *(mutated)* by yourself *(inheriting class)*.
But we can't know everything about the parent private member.

The above code use node.js and not so easy to understand the problem.
I add some more

```
function Parent() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this._secre = 1;
}

Parent.prototype.run = function(x, y) {
  if (this._secre) {
    console.log('run');
  }
};

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this); // call super constructor.
  this._secret = 0; //accidently make the same member name with the parent
}

// subclass extends superclass
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.show = function() {
  this.run();
  console.log("Show my secret -> %s", this._secret);
};

var child = new Child();

console.log('Is child an instance of Child? ' + (child instanceof Child)); // true
console.log('Is child an instance of Parent? ' + (child instanceof Parent)); // true
child.show();
```

It will output

```
Is child an instance of Child? true
Is child an instance of Parent? true
run
Show my secret -> 0
```

But if you accidently name the _secre member of the child with _secret, then you will not get "run output"

```
function Parent() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this._secre = 1;
}

Parent.prototype.run = function(x, y) {
  if (this._secre) {
    console.log('run');
  }
};

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this); // call super constructor.
  this._secre = 0; //accidently make the same member name with the parent
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.show = function() {
  this.run();
  console.log("Show my secret -> %s", this._secre);
};

var child = new Child();

console.log('Is child an instance of Child? ' + (child instanceof Child)); // true
console.log('Is child an instance of Parent? ' + (child instanceof Parent)); // true
child.show();
```

Comment: very dangerous that I couldn't understand the question...

Comment: _Cough cough_. Private member?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way to stop an external script from accessing a "private" variable is to scope that private variable inside a function:

```
;(function() {
    var private_var;
)());
```

In the case of properties of an object that are meant to be used internally within the object, but are not intended to be accessed externally of the object, it is convention to use the underscore prefix naming convention.

```
obj._private
```

But there is nothing actually **stopping** another developer from accessing such a property (if they have access to its parent object) and perhaps changing its value.

Comment: I know the closure pattern. But it's not real inherit in js and most people use the pattern I pointed above. So it's dangerous errrrrr.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to inherit EventEmitter

```
Child.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
Child.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype)
```

Comment: The way you said is in fact the same as I said . node.js just pack your code in the util.inherits and the dangerous code is not in this part. It's the call parent with this . It will assign your this pointer with parent init function.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are not aware this._events is a private variable member in the parent EventEmitter object,

No, it's not private. Go take a look at the source for EventEmitter if you're not convinced.

That said, EventEmitter is an interesting example of how to manage state in JavaScript, worth studying.

What else can we say? JavaScript is not Java. :p